# jQuery Plugin prototype with addons

Tags: jquery-plugins, add-on

I create a free jQuery plugin and what I would like to do is to create some add-ons that will be able for my clients under payment.

So, let's suppose that the free jQuery plugin that I offer for free append hello world into an html `div` tag and I would like to create an add-on that makes the `div` background color red.

Free Version of plugin:

```
(function(window, $) {
    var example = function(elem, options) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;
        this.metadata = this.$elem.data('example-options');
    };

    example.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            message: 'Hello world!'
        },

        init: function() {
            this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);
            this.displayMessage();
            return this;
        },

        displayMessage: function() {
            this.$elem.append('<h1>'+this.config.message+'</h1>');
        }
    }

    example.defaults = example.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.example = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new example(this, options).init();
        });
    };

window.example = example;
})(window, jQuery);
```

And I would like to create an addon that will be in a different js file, like this:

```
example.prototype = {
    bgColor: function() {
        this.$elem.css('background-color', '#f00');
    }
};
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than replacing the default `prototype` that you have created, simply add to it and override methods that you wish to change. For example, you can add your `bgColor` method to the `prototype` as follows:

```
example.prototype.bgColor = function() {
    this.$elem.css('background-color', '#f00');
};
```

To override methods to provide enhanced functionality, you can do the same:

```
example.prototype.displayMessage = function() {
    this.$elem.append('<h1>This message comes from the add-on</h1>');
}
```

Note that for this to work, the add-on js file is included after the default plugin js file.

Comment: Thank you buddy, is what i want ;)